Is there a better way to apply a function to many variables?
I'm making what is essentially a personality quiz in python, and I have a 'question' function that asks a question and then updates each of 12 variables with the answer.
Currently it looks like this:
stat1, stat2, stat3, stat4, stat5, ... = question(stat1, stat2, stat3, stat4, stat5, ...)

Which works fine for like 3 questions, but after that it gets unreadable. So my question is, how can I avoid this? I'm 100% sure there's a way to do this I just don't know how. Is there a way to make a list or a dictionary or something of variables that can be updated independently, or just update the variables from inside the function?

In this case, put the data in a list. As soon as you begin adding numbers to variable names, you should look for a structure to hold all the values.

@Carcigenicate so make a list with 12 different items, change the list with each question, and then assign the items to variables at the end? (clarification)

If all you're doing is updating existing objects with an answer, you would probably just mutate the list in place. Something like: def question(qs): for q in qs: q.answer = some_answer, where q is an object that presumably contains both question and answer members.

"assign the items to variables at the end" - no, never do that. The only variables are your lists, on which you can iterate to access individual items.

The problem is that you have all these variables to begin with. Use a container, like a list or a dict

@AudreySims-Hunt no! Just use the list!

@AudreySims-Hunt To be clear, I was talking about something like this: https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/112784998733deb956a4d45d0e8fba5e. Now, arguably it would be better if questions was treated as immutable and a new list was returned, or that function was a method of the class. My main point though was just to use the list.
